# How to get the total count of two columns from two different tables in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server, `Table1` and `Table2`.

`Table1` contains the information of family head with his age and `Table2` contains the information of family members with their age.

I want to get total count of age. Means if the user enter less than 23 in front end so I will display to user total count of persons less than 23 age from two tables.

My approach is like this:

```
alter procedure example 
   (@age int, @result2 int output)
as
begin
    declare @result int;
    declare @result1 int;

    set @result = (select count(age) from Table1 where age > @age)
    set @result1 = (select count(age) from Table2 where age > @age)

    set @result2 = @result + @result1;
end
```

`hvcid` is the primary key column in my `Table1` and `hvcid` is a foreign key in my `Table2`.

My query shown above returns the result fine. Why not do using join or single query to combine two tables and get the total count of age from two tables?

I don't know how to write using single query? Can you solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way

```
SELECT Sum(cnt) AS total
FROM   (SELECT Count(age) cnt
        FROM   Table1
        WHERE  age > @age
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Count(age)
        FROM   Table2
        WHERE  age > @age) a
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below query to get result from 2 tables :

```
select count(age) + (select count(age) 
    from Table2 where age > @age) 
from Table1 where age > @age
```

Comment: Yes but can i call ExecuteNonQuery() from front end? then it will give result or not in this approach??please if yes or no how can i  get this result  to front end using c#?

Comment: No.ExecuteNonQuery() it gives result as -1. but your select statement gives the correct result.

Comment: ExecuteScalar() method working fine Aliasgar thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**    @Nag

```
select (COUNT(t1.age) + COUNT(t2.age)) as Result
from Table1 t1 
FULL JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.hvcid = t2.hvcid
where t1.age > @age and t2.age > @age
```

Comment: @Nag - IF you use ExecuteScalar(query) then you'll get the result from Code... Hope this helps...

Comment: @khled this query gives some little wrong i have 5 records in my tables. 2 records in table1 and 3 records in table2 so only 5 persons in my table but it gives the age count 6. If i enter >14 age people.

Comment: @Nag - I think there you have to use FULL JOIN instead of INNER  JOIN then.... cause i think there is an extra hvcid in Table2 which is not there in Table1...But  you want all the records of both tables....See my edited  answer...

So use FULL JOIN instead of INNER JOIN... Hope this helps..

Comment: @kheeld but how to get age between two tables? i think full join gives the same result? Ex between 23 and 25 from two tables can i?

Comment: Have you even tried what you are asking everytime? you can try it using this query right? So why aren't you trying it yourself? It'll be much better for you.... Please try what you ask yourself first then if you fail then ask me.... I'll try my best to help you.... Thank you

Comment: Yes i tried myself then only i asked without trying i won't ask Thank You.

Comment: just put this in the query for the between problem @Nag

"where t1.age between 23 AND 25 AND t2.age between 23 AND 25"

I think this'll do... Thank You...